# SQL query giving me wrong order

Tags: php, mysql

Why am i not getting the order i want with this query?

```
SELECT
       e_name,
       a_shortcut,
       GROUP_CONCAT(case
            when t_rank = 1 then  a_shortcut
            when t_rank = 2 then  a_shortcut
            when t_rank = 3 then  a_shortcut
            end separator ',') as group_con 
        FROM team 
        INNER JOIN event 
        ON team.EID = event.eid 
        WHERE e_type = 'nonsport'  
        GROUP BY event.eid ORDER BY t_rank
```

This query gives me a random order all the time when i input the t_rank. It is not giving me a 1,2,3 order but instead it gives me random all the time. Can someone help me pls?

Here is the result that is giving me

```
 {"nresults":[{"e_name":"Musical Festival - Song Composition","First":"2nd",
"Second":"1st",
"Third":"3rd"}]}
```

Here is my expected output

```
    {"nresults":[{"e_name":"Musical Festival - Song Composition","First":"1st",
"Second":"2nd",
"Third":"3rd"}]}
```

[image]

Comment: how do i fixed this sir? i am parsing it in json

Comment: i dont follow sir

Comment: If you mean the  group_concat is not ordered then you should use group_concat with the order by clause? Sample data would be nice.

Comment: posted a sample data sir

Comment: Where should i put the order by clause?

Comment: Sorry what I meant was sample data from team and event.

Comment: posted an image of the table teams sir. The EID is taken from event table

Comment: Try to Add ASC order for your query

Comment: doesnt work sir

Comment: You can use ORDER BY inside the GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: yeap got it working. Thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it working now. Thanks everyone.

```
 select
              e_name,
              a_shortcut,
              GROUP_CONCAT(case
                when t_rank = 1 then  a_shortcut
                when t_rank = 2 then  a_shortcut
                when t_rank = 3 then  a_shortcut
              end order by t_rank separator ',') as group_con 
            from
              team inner join event on team.EID = event.eid Where e_type = 'nonsport' 
group by event.eid
```

i just move the order by clause after the end before the separator inside the group_concat